# Сумма строк, имеющих одинаковое значений

Tags: sql, запрос

Есть таблица с данными. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как мне получить сумму значений discount тех строк, где значения поля by_recomended одинаковые? (сумма по бобкову, докторову и т.д)?

Comment: В чём у вас затруднение в решении этой задачи?  Какая БД или только ANSI?

Comment: Используйте функцию `sum()` и предложение `group by`

Answer (score 1):

Судя по скрину, это скорее всего MS SQL Server. Вот запрос:

```
SELECT SUM([discount]), [by_recomended] FROM [your_table] GROUP BY [by_recomended]
```

Answer (score 0):

Часто интересны и другие значения из таблицы, тогда подойдет оконная ф-я SUM:

```
SELECT t.*, SUM(discount) OVER (PARTITION BY by_recomended) sum_discount     
FROM table1 t
ORDER BY by_recomended, id
```

PS не забывайте указывать сорировку в конце запроса.