# Помогите с написанием Sql запроса для связи,многие к многим

Tags: sql

Добрый день, имеется база, с построением как показано на картинке внизу,необходимо найти сумму всех number_of_lecture, которые читаются в одном курсе, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну попытки то вы какие нибудь делали решить эту задачу, `select name_of_course, sum(number_of_lecture)` откуда нить там типа `from course inner join ... inner join...`, или просто `from course, ... ... where ...` ?

Comment: к сожалению вообще не понимаю как начать(

Comment: Напишите простой запрос: свяжите все три таблицы, и выберите все поля. Посмотрите результат. Представьте, что это - не запрос, а такая таблица. Как из неё получить нужное? запрос элементарен - напишите его. А затем подставьте в него исходные имена полей и таблиц.

Comment: Вот суммирование готовой таблицы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599265/ а делайте такую из 3х с помощью join

Comment: то есть должно быть что то типа такого 
'(select disciplines.number_of_lecture,course_disciplines
from disciplines inner join disciplines on disciplines.id_of_disciplines=course_discipline.id_of_discipline)'

Comment: @МихаилФаузель должно быть так, чтобы берем таблицу курсов, присоединяем к ней таблицу связи курс-дисциплина, и присоединяем к ним таблицу дисциплин.

Comment: так? но почему то всё равно выдаёт ошибку'select sum(number_of_lecture),name_of_course
From
(SELECT number_of_lecture,name_of_course
  FROM (( course_disciplines
  INNER JOIN disciplines on disciplines.id_of_decipline=course_disciplines.id_of_discipline)
  Inner Join course on course.id_of_course=course_disciplines.id_course))
  Group by id_course'

Comment: как то вы все усложняете. `select .... from course inner join course_disciplines on ... inner join disciplines on .... group by ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    c.id_of_course, 
    c.name_of_course,  
    sum(d.number_of_lecture)
from 
    course c
    join course_disciplines cd on cd.id_course = c.id_of_course
    join disciplines d on d.id_of_discipline = cd.id_of_discipline
group by
    c.id_of_course, 
    c.name_of_course
```