# SQL запрос количество одинаковых записей по дням

Tags: sql-server, count

в базе есть таблица реестр в нём столбцы DEALDATE и Transactio 
в столбе DEALDATE загружаться даты а в Transactio есть 2 разных значение такие как "Продажа" "Возврат". Мне надо в запросе написать по дате количество Продаж например 
|15.01.18|20|
|16.01.18|12|
Помогите пожалуйста с запросом

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сумма строк, имеющих одинаковое значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599265/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT  COUNT(Transactio) AS koli4estvo, CAST(DEALDATE as date) FROM TICKET 
WHERE Transactio='Продажа' group by CAST(DEALDATE as date) order by CAST(DEALDATE as date)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Transactio, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DEALDATE,104)+'|'+CAST(COUNT(1) AS VARCHAR(10)) txt
FROM table
GROUP BY Transactio, DEALDATE

Comment: select DEALDATE, count(Transactio)
from TICKET
WHERE DEALDATE >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetDate())- 7,0) and Transactio='Продажа'
GROUP BY DEALDATE сделала таким образом  но количество Продаж считает по дате и времени, как сделать только по дате например |18.01.2018|20|  помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Уберите время из dealdate, например, CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),dealdate,112) AS DATETIME), или cast(dealdate as date)  и в выборке и в группировке