# подсчет mysql значений

Tags: mysql, sql

есть таблица со столбцом source id  нужно подсчитать количиство повторяющихся столбоцов и вывести их оличество с самим source_id пример

```
source_id
123
111
123
112
111
123

вывод 
source_id 123 count 3
source_id 111 count 2
source_id 112 count 1
```

как такое можно вывести в mysql буду благодарен за любые идеи помощь

Comment: `select source_id, count(1) from table group by source_id`

Comment: @Mike Выставите как ответ помечу как ответ

Comment: Думаю надо найти дубль вопроса, коих наверняка пара тысяч есть. просто их найти не зная ответа очень тяжело :) А у меня как назло есть ссылки на получение суммы, а не количества, вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599265/194569

Comment: @Mike FirePlay :)